# Getting "Class extends type annotation appeared on a non class target" When trying to implement entityManagerFactory using Java -cp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Please do not respond with use mvn spring-boot:run or java -jar**

I have the following config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.pkg.repository")
public class MyConfig {
    @Autowired
    DatasourceConfig config;
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("my.pkg.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(config.getDatasource());
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run via `java -cp` I get the following....

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [my/package/MyConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class extends type annotation appeared on a non class target

What am I missing?

**How am I building/running**

1. `mvn clean package -U`
2. `java -cp "target/lib.jar:resource/dir:other/jar/lib.jar" my.pkg.Application`

**Full Stacktrace**

```
12:20:43.775 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [my/pkg/Config.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class extends type annotation appeared on a non class target
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
        at my.pkg.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class extends type annotation appeared on a non class target
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processTypeAnnotation(Indexer.java:538)
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processTypeAnnotations(Indexer.java:515)
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processAttributes(Indexer.java:355)
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processMethodInfo(Indexer.java:306)
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1598)
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can @Bean appear on methods? The error message sounds like that isn't the case

Comment: @f1sh `@Bean` is usable _only_ on methods. The problem appears to be inside the JPA scanning process.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, why do you have this config _at all_? Boot does this for you automatically, and you only need to set a couple of properties.

Comment: @f1sh of course it can, that's not it

Comment: @Eugene maven so I assume javac

Comment: Does setPackagesToScan recurse the file? Sidenote and curious the class is in the root of that file

Comment: this is what I thought. `jandex`, upgrade to at least `2.2.2.Final` and this should go away

Comment: @Eugene That looks like it solved the issue, thank you I can accept that answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `jandex` issue (the library that throws that Exception). I remember we had the same issue once, and there was a defect on github for that. It was fixed in `2.2.2.Final` version - so you should upgrade to that.

The maven deps should be...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>[2.2.3.Final,)</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, not even sure I want to know how long you spent on that one.

Comment: Do we know spec which versions of spring this will be a prob?